# UE4 trying to create a material or edit a pre-made material throws Error [SM5] metallib: Invalid bitcode file

Tags: material-design, unreal-engine4, bitcode

After importing a model I made in Blender I went to throw a material on it but whenever I try to make my own material or customize a pre-existing one I get the error:

'Error [SM5] /tmp/9524_4129856322.metal(0): metallib: Invalid bitcode file!'

I've tried updating UE4 but the problem still exists and 'support bitcode in shipping' is turned off in project settings. I'm really stuck and not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my own question a friend in class said it happened to him as well and just to uninstall the engine and reinstall. Sure enough, an hour later worth of installing it the error went away.